# Video autoplay on Safari 11

Tags: video, safari, html5-video

Hi have noticed video does not auto play on safari 11 anymore. Below is my code it works on Chrome as it has to be muted. It just shows the poster image. Any Help.

```
<video width="100%" poster="poster_url.png" autoplay muted playsinline>
<source src="video_url.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 13):

The below autoplays for me on Safari 11.1.2 on OSX 10.12.6

```html
<video width="100%" poster="poster_url.png" autoplay muted playsinline>
<source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/trailer/trailer_480p.mov" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The rules do changes quite often and it is also possible for a user or organisation to set their own preferences, so the Safari team recommend that you check in your code always to see if the video is able to auto play:

```js
var promise = document.querySelector('video').play();

if (promise !== undefined) {
    promise.catch(error => {
        // Auto-play was prevented
        // Show a UI element to let the user manually start playback
    }).then(() => {
        // Auto-play started
    });
}
```

More details here at the time of writing:

- https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/

Comment: @PaulSlocum - you mean the code snippet? I just tested it on Safari 12.01 and OSX 10.13.16 and it worked for me. Do you maybe have some preferences set in your browser to stop autoplay? The video has white borders so it may be worth scrolling the box if your browser window is small to see the video itself.

Comment: Stopping autoplay is the default on the latest version.  Telling everybody who goes to your webpage to go into settings and change settings is obviously not an option.  Your answer was the standard answer before, but does not work with the default browser settings now.

Comment: @PaulSlocum Safari 12.0.1 is the latest Safari version and I just verified it on two separate machines and the above snippet, plus a simple test site using this code as an extra check, autoplays without any adjustment to default browser settings. Maybe I am misunderstanding your comments?

Comment: @PaulSlocum - for completeness also tested on iOS 11.2.6 running the latest Safari and it also autoplays there.

Comment: It was not working in whatever version of Safari 11 I was using, but are right that it seems to work in Safari 12 on both MacOS and iOS