# Does anyone know how to autoplay a video in Safari?

Tags: html, safari

I have this piece of code and seems to be working fine in Chrome, Firefox, Explorer but not in Safari, iPhone nor iPad.

```
<video preload="true" autoplay="autoplay" loop muted playsinline #video>
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/webm" /></video>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Video autoplay on Safari 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51837051/video-autoplay-on-safari-11)

Answer (score 0):

This code with simple attributes works in safari iPhone:

```
<video autoplay muted loop playsinline>
```

Check your device battery. With **low battery mode** videos do not autoplay.

Don't know what means your `#video` attribute. Maybe you meant `id="video"`

Comment: Yeah, that #video is for angular DOM selection. But with the attributes you mention still shows a blank space (where video should go) in Safari...