# Html video tag not support ios/iphone

Tags: html, angular, video, tags

hi i created responsive website, for android it is working fine but for ios/iphone it does not showing me the videos and thumbnail till i click play button what could be the issue,

here is my some html code and  iphone screenshots

[here is the iphone screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Im3AA.jpg)

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div id="ls-video">
        <ol>
            <li *ngFor="let animalvideo of Animalvideos">
            
                <video class="mycheck"   (click)="videoshow(animalvideo)" preload="metadata" controls [src]="'http://54.172.101.222:8080/'+animalvideo.filePath" type="video/mp4"   playsinline loop muted ></video>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <div id="video-play">
        <video id="video-side" preload="metadata" [src]="'http://54.172.101.222:8080/'+selectedVD" type="video/mp4" alta="show" controls   playsinline loop muted ></video>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Video autoplay on Safari 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51837051/video-autoplay-on-safari-11)

Comment: i am using angular and nodejs, please any one can help me

thanks